# Crystal Reports: positioning image outside page margins

Tags: image, crystal-reports, report, margin

In my report I have a left page margin of 2.3cm. Nothing is allowed inside of the margin except in some cases a specific image on the first page. How can I do that without changing the page margins? The margins have to be set this way because of some printing issues where I have to change the margins on every even page.

Comment: Can you post the image

Comment: why is the image important? I'm not allowed to post the image.

Comment: It is difficult to understand where you placed the image and where it crossed the border....

Comment: I placed the image on the left side of a page header. But the image is always placed over the text of the reports because the data is also placed on the left side of the details sections. Apart from this fact the image has to be on the left margin of the report. But I can't position the image inside the page margins.